# Visual Studio 2019 publish prerequisites dialog is missing .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: visual-studio, .net-framework

I've installed the "developer pack" (.NET Framework 4.8 SDK plus whatever VS magic) from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48

I've updated VS2019 to update 2 (16.0.2).

But if I try to set a prerequisite of .NET 4.8,
it is not listed in the options in the dialog box:

[image: publish prerequisite dialog]

Anyone know where/how to get the appropriate prerequisite package from?

Comment: Looking for an answer to this as well. Anyone?

Comment: That issue is [tracked on developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/549135/net-framework-48-not-available-as-clickonce-prereq.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a [solution on VS Developer Community website](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52075/net-framework-47-not-available-as-clickonce-prereq.html#reply-98247) which also works to add the **.NET Framework 4.8** to the **Prerequisites dialog**.

The trick is, to pretend the installer that VS 2015 is installed:

1. Create this path (if not exist):
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages`
2. On **64 bit machine**, create the registry key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\14.0`
   On **32 bit machine**, create the registry key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\14.0`
3. In the just created `14.0` key, create a String named `Path` with the just created folder path as value
   (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages`).
4. Run the .NET 4.8 developer pack setup `ndp48-devpack-enu.exe` (Repair or Install).
5. Remove the registry key from step 2 (only if you created it).
6. Copy the `DotNetFX48` folder from the created path (step 1)
   to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages`
7. Restart Visual Studio.

Note:

- Setting the `Path` string value to the actual target path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages`) will not work.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can download "bootstrapper package for .Net framework 4.8" from [github](https://github.com/heckl/bootstrapper-package-for-.net-framework-4.8). Copy the DotNetFX48 folder into the proper place e.g.: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages` and restart Visual Studio.